# How to Add 'Invoice Ninja" in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, invoice, invoice-ninja

"composer require hillelcoren/invoice-ninja" is not working for  me and giving the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- hillelcoren/invoice-ninja v2.4.5 requires laravel/framework 5.0.* -> no matching package found.
- hillelcoren/invoice-ninja v2.4.4 requires laravel/framework 5.0.* -> no matching package found.
- hillelcoren/invoice-ninja v2.4.3 requires laravel/framework 5.0.* -> no matching package found.
- hillelcoren/invoice-ninja v2.4.2 requires laravel/framework 5.0.* -> no matching package found.
- hillelcoren/invoice-ninja v2.4.1 requires laravel/framework 5.0.* -> no matching package found.
- hillelcoren/invoice-ninja v2.4.0 requires laravel/framework 5.0.* -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for hillelcoren/invoice-ninja ^2.4 -> satisfiable by hillelcoren/invoice-ninja[v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5].

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Does it means that NinjaInvoice doesn't support the newr versions of Laravel? Please someone solve the issue.

Comment: According to the [`composer.json`](https://github.com/hillelcoren/invoice-ninja/blob/master/composer.json#L17) file of the package it only supports Laravel 5.0.*, so you're out of luck so far. I suggest you open an [issue](https://github.com/hillelcoren/invoice-ninja/issues) with the package and ask for 5.1 support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bogdan suggests, this package is only available on Laravel 5.0.* according to the packages `[composer.json][1]`.

When it comes to installing packages, they can have their own dependencies or packages that they subsequently require to run and in this case it is formatted to run on 5.0.* and so running Laravel 5.1 makes it incompatible.

Again, as Bogdan suggests, logging an issue is a great way to see if they can support 5.1.

Looking at the open issues, you've since done this and opened [one](https://github.com/hillelcoren/invoice-ninja/issues/504).

In the meantime, you will either have to wait for 5.1 support or look for a similar package.

*Original comment given by Bogdan, however posting as an answer to give an official answer.*